# How can I use GridListView with firebase?

Tags: flutter, gridview, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have a question about GridListView with firestore.

I want to use GridList with firestore but some errors are happen.

> lib/main.dart:75:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'children'. children: workoutList ^^^^^^^^ ../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:1729:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. GridView.builder({

Could you give me some ideas?

```
return GridView.builder(
              
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2),

      children: workoutList
        .map(
            (workout) => CheckboxListTile(

              title: Text(
                workout.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),
              ),
              value: workout.isDone,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
                model.reload();
              },

    ),
    )
        .toList()
  );
```

Comment: "some errors are happen" Please edit your question to include the exact error and stack trace.

Comment: lib/main.dart:75:15: Error: No named parameter with the name 'children'.
              children: workoutList
              ^^^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:1729:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  GridView.builder({

Comment: It looks like `GridView.builder` doesn't have a property named `children`? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html

Comment: answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582633/gridview-with-flutter-and-firestore). There are no children property and what's most important are `itemBuilder` and `itemCount` props

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explanatory. All it's telling you is that the `GridView.builder()` constructor has no parameter 'children'. The code below is way to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate:
  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemCount: workoutList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    var workout = workoutList[index];
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(
        workout.title,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      value: workout.isDone,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        workout.isDone = !workout.isDone;
        model.reload();
      },
    );
  },
);
```